# ssh port forwarding two routers

Tags: networking, router, ssh, port-forwarding

[moved from StackExchange, where I posted by mistake]

Not sure how to debug this one...

Router 1 forwards wan xyz to the wan address of Router 2, xyz, which is then forwarded to host 22:

```
Router1:xyz -> Router2:xyz -> host:22
```

`ssh Router2:xyz` works fine when connected to Router1.  If I set up a host under Router1 with standard port forwarding (`Router1:xyz -> host2:22`) then `ssh Router1(wan) -p xyz` works fine.  However, with the original forwarding scheme, `ssh Router1(wan) -p xyz` fails (and with `-vvv` shows no connection made and timeout).

Any idea how to go about debugging this?  (host correctly identifies Router2 as default gateway/route)

Answer (score 0):

Turns out something very odd is happening this end: any port forward for ssh except port 22 fails to work.  For the time being I'm using multihop, which isn't as slow as I feared, but this problem seems to lie with the ISP (Virgin Media).

I'll take it up with them; looks like it's failing outside the home network.

Comment: So is this additional information and you still need help (in which case, add this to your question rather than posting it as an answer), or have you determined that it is an ISP problem, you have a satisfactory workaround, and you're putting the question to bed?

Comment: sorry for the delay.  The problem lies with the ISP, and I have a workaround for now before I bother them.  I'll edit the answer.